# Difference between a basic for-loop and a for-in-loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

In which situations using

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

is different from using

```
for (var i in array)
```

in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays check this out also possible duplicate

Comment: this question has answer so you can not delete it.

Comment: Wait awhile and it will get enough votes to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

is best for traversing an array, visiting all of the array elements in order.

On modern javascript engines, `array.forEach` is often cleaner.

```
for (var i in object) // with object.hasOwnProperty
```

is used to go through the enumerable properties of an OBJECT, including inherited enumerable properties.  Order is not assured.  Though an array is an object and this method "works" for arrays, it isn't ideal as returned properties may not be in any particular order.  In addition, if any monkey patches or shims are put into place on the array object, they can show up here.

Comment: That is why people confuse Javascript properties with associative arrays.  They do have a number of points in common, including being able to iterate over them.  Now, of course, not all properties can be iterated over.  Host objects follow their own rules and `strict mode` gives the option of making some properties `DontEnum`.