# Iterating data to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following loop

```
for (var i in data) {
   console.log(data[i])
}
```

Data that I for loop is iterating through is

```
 "data": [
    {
      "MainArea": "North West"
    },
    {
      "MainArea": "South West"
    },
```

When I run it I get following output in firebug

```
[Object { MainArea="North West"}, 
Object {  MainArea="South West"}]
```

What I am trying to get is just the value of it. So that when I tried

```
console.log(data[i].MainArea)
```

Hoping to get just the "North West" and South West" values, instead 
       I get "undefined" in my console.

Comment: see the answer below, you need to iterate through `data.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the data object you are iterating has another property called data which is an array containing the target objects, and of course the property key you need to use is `MainArea` so try

```
var data = {
    "data": [{
        "MainArea": "North West"
    }, {
        "MainArea": "South West"
    }]
}
for (var i in data.data) {
    console.log(data.data[i].MainArea)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hyDP2/)

Answer (score 5):

Try following:

```
console.log(data[i].MainArea);
```

You are trying to get information out of objects property. Since your variables enclosed to json format list you can reach your variables through named properties.

**UPDATE:** According your addition to the your original question I created **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/4CQNQ/2/)**.

```
var myObj = {"data": [
                        {
                          "MainArea": "North West"
                        },
                        {
                          "MainArea": "South West"
                        },
                    ],
           },
    data = myObj['data'],
    data_length=data.length;

for (var i= 0; i < data_length; i++)
{
   console.log(data[i].MainArea);
}
```

Keep in mind that when you are iterating key value pairs you should use `for ... in` loop while when you are iterating through array you should use `for` loop. For example if your `data` property contains sorted array, `for ... in` loop will not guaranty to loop from array item `0` to `N`. It means it will not follow sequence. So use only `for` loops for array and `for ... in` for non-array objects. Read about this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292523/difference-between-a-basic-for-loop-and-a-for-in-loop-in-javascript). Some jsPerf comparison be seen [here](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-vs-for-in-loop).

Comment: Ok. Can you publish your `data` object initialization?

Comment: I just updated the code with original data. I am getting this data from stored procedure. Everything is working fine, I just cant figure out how to just get the Value part i.e "North West" ..thanks

Comment: Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/4CQNQ/1/). Sorry I was busy and cannot provide answer timely :(

Answer (score 1):

The object is defined as this:

```
{ MainArea="North West" }
```

So it has only one property, called `MainArea`.  There's no property called `value` so of course `value` is `undefined`.  Try:

```
console.log(data[i].MainArea)
```

Comment: That isn't proper JS syntax.  Object properties are `key: value`, not `key=value`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Valid point, but the syntax here seems to be what he's seeing in his debugger.  It's just copied/pasted from the question.